# .NetStandard and Xamarin.Forms Android compatibility

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

According to the [.NET implementation support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard):

`.NetStandard` 1.x only supports `Xamarin.Android` 7 and above

`.NetStandard` 2 only supports `Xamarin.Android` 8 and above

So I have avoided upgrading my pcls to .netstandard assuming I couldn't support Android 5.1+.

However in a recent test, I have converted an entire Android app i.e `Xamarin.Forms PCL` to `.NetStandard 2 class library` and it works flawlessly on every platform (in both emulator and physical devices from Android 5.1+ upwards).

This has been confusing to say the least. Is it the case that something may break, or some features may not work or will i have some compatibility issue I'm unaware of? Or am I not understanding the .NET implementation support page and associated concepts correctly?

Comment: when working with xamarin.forms i didn't get it above 1.0 due to the netframework4.5.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane  . i wasn't expecting it to work at all, which is why i am so confused. though with XF 2.5 and converting my pcl to .netstandard 2 it just seemed to work (after i sorted the nugets)

Comment: Are you confused that is runs on an Android 5 device? The support for the new SDK is the build environment and tooling - you can always build an app using a later version of the Android SDK and run it on an earlier one.

Comment: @JimBobBennett yeah this i think is the major confusion... and this makes a lot of sense when said like that

Comment: "Xamarin.Android 8 and above" has a different meaning from "Android 5.1+" (they totally refer to different things). So you should think twice of what you have observed and find the correct way to understand the facts. I personally see no confusing part at all.

Comment: @LexLi Yes i agree, and i'm slowly starting to understand the facts . however i'm guessing others might fall into this trap, so i will leave the question open for a suitable explanation. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can read in-depth explanation on Xamarin official webpage:](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#Android_Versions_and_API_Levels)

> As the Android platform evolves and new Android versions are released,
>   each Android version is assigned a unique integer identifier, called
>   the API Level. Therefore, each Android version corresponds to a single
>   Android API Level. Because users install apps on older as well as the
>   most recent versions of Android, real-world Android apps must be
>   designed to work with multiple Android API levels.
>
> Each release of Android goes by multiple names:
>
> - The Android version, such as Android 7.1
> - A code name, such as Nougat A
> - corresponding API level, such as API level 25
>
> An Android code name may
>   correspond to multiple versions and API levels (as seen in the list
>   below), but each Android version corresponds to exactly one API level.
>
> In addition, Xamarin.Android defines build version codes that map to
>   the currently known Android API levels. The following list can help
>   you translate between API level, Android version, code name, and
>   Xamarin.Android build version code.
>
> API 26 (Android 8.0) – Oreo, released August 2017.
>
> API 25 (Android 7.1) – Nougat, released
>   December 2016.
>
> .....

Comment: so Xamarin.Android 8 is equivalent to Android API level 8?

Comment: Not API level, but the public android version (8.0) in that example.